# Subquery with variable in where

Tags: mysql, table, where, table-variable

I don't know why but if I do the `subquery` where in the first `LEFT JOIN` with the value of the variable `@id` it does not return any results, it is as if the value of `@id` was always null.

**But why not do the `LEFT JOIN` directly?**

Simple, the table is large and the query is taking horrors to execute, so it would be much faster.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT @id := p.id_pen,
    p.id_env_pen,
   
    0 AS id_star,
    FALSE AS is_star,
       
    u.id_user AS sender_id,
    u.name_user AS sender_name,

    u2.id_user AS response_id,
    u2.name_user AS response_name,
       
    p.text_pen AS text_send,
    p2.text_pen AS text_response,
       
    DATE_FORMAT(p.created_at_pen, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS send_datetime,
    DATE_FORMAT(p2.created_at_pen, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS response_datetime,
       
    p.time_res_pen,
    p.state_pen,
    p.created_at_pen
FROM pendency AS p
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            p2.id_pen,
            p2.text_pen,    
            p2.created_at_pen,
            p2.id_pen_req_pen
        FROM pendency AS p2
        WHERE p2.id_pen_req_pen = @id 
        # HERE, I try do `= p.id_pen` but dont works too, 
        # id not identify the alias from outside
    ) AS p2 ON p2.id_pen_req_pen = @id
    
    INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id_user = p.id_user_pen
    LEFT JOIN users AS u2 ON u2.id_user = p.id_user_req_pen
WHERE (p.id_user_pen = '5' AND p.id_user_req_pen != -10)
OR p.id_user_req_pen = '5'
```

CREATE TABLES

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    `id_user` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `id_fs_user` VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT 'Não informado',
    `email_user` VARCHAR(105) DEFAULT 'Não informado',
    `pass_user` VARCHAR(35) DEFAULT 'Não informado',
    `name_user` VARCHAR(120) DEFAULT 'Não informado',
    `cpf_user` VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT 'Não informado',
    `type_user` VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT 'master',
    `work_week_user` INT DEFAULT 5,
    `is_block_user` BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
    `permission_id_user` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `attendant_user` BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
    `version_id_user` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `last_login_user` DATETIME,
    `last_move_user` DATETIME,

    `id_user_user` INT DEFAULT 0,
    `created_at_user` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `safe_del_date_user` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `safe_del_state_user` BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
    `safe_del_user_user` INT DEFAULT 0);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pendency` (
    `id_pen` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_env_pen` INT NOT NULL,
    `text_pen` TEXT,
    `id_user_req_pen` INT DEFAULT 0,
    `id_pen_req_pen` INT DEFAULT 0,
    `time_res_pen` INT NOT NULL,
    `state_pen` BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
    `id_old_pen` INT NOT NULL,
    `id_user_pen` INT NOT NULL,
    `created_at_pen` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_env_pen`) REFERENCES `env`(`id_env`) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Comment: User variables are updated as a result is returned. They aren't an alias. Your subselect could just be an ordinary left join `on 2.id_pen_req_pen = p.id_pen`.

Comment: @danblack But if I use the alias in the where of the subquery it doesn't identify

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` for the tables involved and edit this into your question. Lets see if some correct indexing to improve speed rather than broken use of user variables to fix it.

Comment: @danblack done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your query performance is that `x = 5 or y = 5` queries don't usually use indexes.

We help this out with your code by creating greatest and least values as generated columns with indexes.

```
alter TABLE `pendency`
add lpen int as (least(id_user_pen,id_user_req_pen)),
add gpen int as (greatest(id_user_pen,id_user_req_pen)),
add index gpen(gpen),
add index lpen(lpen);
```

Then use a union, first to grap those with 5 as the greater user (talking to 1-4) and then 5 as the least talking to the others.

```
(
SELECT
    p.id_pen,
    p.id_env_pen,
    0 AS id_star,
    FALSE AS is_star,
    p.text_pen AS text_send,
    p2.text_pen AS text_response,   
    DATE_FORMAT(p.created_at_pen, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS send_datetime,
    DATE_FORMAT(p2.created_at_pen, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS response_datetime,
       
    p.time_res_pen,
    p.state_pen,
    p.created_at_pen
FROM pendency AS p
JOIN pendency p2 ON
  p2.id_pen_req_pen = p1.id_pen
  AND p.gpen= 5
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT
    p.id_pen,
    p.id_env_pen,
    0 AS id_star,
    FALSE AS is_star,
    p.text_pen AS text_send,
    p2.text_pen AS text_response,   
    DATE_FORMAT(p.created_at_pen, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS send_datetime,
    DATE_FORMAT(p2.created_at_pen, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS response_datetime,
       
    p.time_res_pen,
    p.state_pen,
    p.created_at_pen
FROM pendency AS p
JOIN pendency p2 ON
  p2.id_pen_req_pen = p1.id_pen
  AND p.lpen= 5
)
```

Joining to `users`, handling of (`id_user_req_pen!= -10`) and ordering has been left as an exercise to the reader you.

Comment: works fine, tks